# How to pass multiple values to a parameter which also correspond with other parameters?

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, url-parameters

In order to do reporting on my domain, I have a need to pass multiple parameters through the URL and also pass their corresponding values.

Simple Example - Single value for each

`http://localhost/myapp/search?
  filtertype=status&filterterm=pending`

Complex Example - Multiple values -

`http://localhost/myapp/search?
  filtertype=status&filtertype=color&filterterm=pending&filterterm=red`

I can get these values as a list using `params.list("filtertype")` & `params.list("filterterm")` but this way they won't have any correlation among them.

**My question** is how would I make my criteria query based on these values such that I don't have to hardcode the array index for `filterterm` as I am doing in the solution below?

```
def filteredResults(params) {
  def filtertypes = params.list("filtertype")
  def filterterms = params.list("filterterm")

  def list = MyDomain.createCriteria().list(max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0) {
    if ("status" in filtertypes) {
      eq("status", filterterms[0])
    }
    if ("color" in filtertypes) {
      eq("color", filterterms[1])
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in the above solution I am hard coding `filterterms[0] etc..` this will not scale well. I need a solution that will scale well to multiple values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `eachWithIndex` like this?:

```
def filteredResults(params) {
  def filtertypes = params.list("filtertype")
  def filterterms = params.list("filterterm")

  def list = MyDomain.createCriteria().list(max: params.max?: 10, offset: params.offset?: 0) {
    filtertypes.eachWithIndex { ft, idx ->
      eq("${ft}", filterterms[idx])
    }
  }
}
```